# POST List<object> from Angular2 Service to SpringBoot RestController

Tags: json, angular, post, spring-boot, angular2-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuARC.png)Hi I am actually making an application in Angular2(Frontend) and Springboot(Backend).
Uptill now , I have made many request from angular2 to Springboot i.e GET ;POST .I have even sent single Json object from Angular2 service to Springboot .

But currently I have a scenario where I need to send List of Json object from Angular2 to Springboot Rest controller .but unfortunately I am unable to do that .

what I am doing is

1: I have made an array of Type for which I need to send object in angular2 .
2:Pushed individual json object of same txpe into that array
3.Passed that array to service of angular2 in function call.
4.Finally made a POST request to Springboot Controller

below is my function to add JSon object to array :

```
updateChecked(value, event) {
    // console.log(event.target.getAttribute('value'));

    if (event.target.checked) {
        // this.checkArr.push(event.target.getAttribute('value'));
        this.checkArr.push({
            profil_id: event.target.getAttribute('value'),
            profil_name_lang: null,
            profil_name_short: null,
            geschaeftsbereich: null,
            spezialberatung: null
        });
    } else if (!event.target.checked) {
        //let indexx = this.checkArr.indexOf(event.target.getAttribute('value'));
        let indexx = this.checkArr.findIndex(_profile => _profile.profil_id === event.target.getAttribute('value'));
        this.checkArr.splice(indexx, 1);
        console.log(indexx);
    }
}
```

below is my Angular2 service function

```
private _deleteURL = 'http://localhost:9000//deleteprofile'
private headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

deleteProfile(chckArr: Profile[]): Promise < Profile > {
    // console.log("karan in delete");
    console.log(chckArr);
    return this.http
        .post(this._deleteURL, chckArr, {
            headers: this.headers1
        })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as Profile)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

below is my Springboot Funtion :-

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deleteprofile")
 public void deleteProfile(@RequestBody List < Profile > profile) { // function to delete an existing profiles 

     try {
         //     profileservice.deleteProfile(profile);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

entity class in Angular2

```
export class Profile {
    profil_id: string;
    profil_name_lang: string;
    profil_name_short: string;
    geschaeftsbereich: string;
    spezialberatung: string;
}
```

entity class in Springboot

```
package permissionbackendservice.permissionmatrix.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


@Entity
//@IdClass(ActivityId.class)
@Table(name = "T_DM_VM_PROFILE_DIM")

public class Profile implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PROFIL_ID")
    private String profil_id = null;


    @Column(name = "PROFIL_NAME_LANG")
    private String profil_name_lang = null;

    @Column(name = "PROFIL_NAME_KURZ")
    private String profil_name_short = null;

    @Column(name = "GESCHAEFTSBEREICH")
    private String geschaeftsbereich = null;

    @Column(name = "SPEZIALBERATUNG")
    private String spezialberatung = null;




    public String getProfil_id() {
        return profil_id;
    }

    public void setProfil_id(String profil_id) {
        this.profil_id = profil_id;
    }

    public String getProfil_name_lang() {
        return profil_name_lang;
    }

    public void setProfil_name_lang(String profil_name_lang) {
        this.profil_name_lang = profil_name_lang;
    }

    public String getProfil_name_short() {
        return profil_name_short;
    }

    public void setProfil_name_short(String profil_name_short) {
        this.profil_name_short = profil_name_short;
    }

    public String getGeschaeftsbereich() {
        return geschaeftsbereich;
    }

    public void setGeschaeftsbereich(String geschaeftsbereich) {
        this.geschaeftsbereich = geschaeftsbereich;
    }

    public String getSpezialberatung() {
        return spezialberatung;
    }

    public void setSpezialberatung(String spezialberatung) {
        this.spezialberatung = spezialberatung;
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: con you post the backend log too?

Comment: There is no error or message generated in the backend ,,, The call just dosent come to springboot

Comment: CAN ANYBODY PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Change your Controller **deleteProfile()** method using an array for the **@RequestBody** like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deleteprofile")
 public void deleteProfile(@RequestBody Profile[] profile) { 
 // function to delete an existing profiles 

     try {
         //     profileservice.deleteProfile(profile);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

If the profileservice.deleteProfile() require a list of profile instead of an array you can get it using  **Arrays.asList(profile)**

On the client side, you have to send **application/json** request. So update your client request by deleting the header :

```
private _deleteURL = 'http://localhost:9000/deleteprofile'

deleteProfile(chckArr: Profile[]): Promise < Profile > {
    // console.log("karan in delete");
    console.log(chckArr);
    return this.http
        .post(this._deleteURL, chckArr)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as Profile)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

It's not an issue but you forget trailing "/" in your url too.

**[UPDATE WITH WORKING CODE](https://github.com/freemanpolys/jhipster-labs) :**

Rest controller in Person microservice :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomController {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomController.class);

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/deleteperson")
    public ResponseEntity deletePerson(@RequestBody Person[] persons) {
        log.info(" Batch delete " + persons);
        personService.delete(Arrays.asList(persons));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

Angular service in the gateway :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Person} from './person.model';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class CustomService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    batchDelete(persons: Person[]): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('/person/api/deleteperson', persons);
    }

}
```

Delete method int person.component.ts:

```
batchDelete() {
    console.log('--- delete ---- ' + JSON.stringify(this.people));
    this.customService.batchDelete(this.people).subscribe( (res) => {
        this.eventManager.broadcast({ name: 'personListModification', content: 'Delete them all'});

    });
}
```

[CODE ON GITHUB](https://github.com/freemanpolys/jhipster-labs)

Results :
BEFORE
[image: Before batch delete]

AFTER DELETE 
[image]

Comment: thanks mate tried your solution but ,,I am getting another error on browser console :- status:415 :"url encoded" not supported ,"path":"//deleteprofile". I have added a screenshot as well . kindly have a look and suggest something

Comment: when send using application/json , it given me error on browser console --> unexpected end of json .I guess its expecting a single json ,,, and when I send  array of json , it cant handle it

Comment: Tried this one as well ,, it says unexpected end of JSon input ,maybe it expect just a json

Comment: Yes, you have to send an array of json like your angular client is set actually because your Spring  method deleteProfile(@RequestBody Profile[] profile) is expecting an array of Profile. If it still not work, i'll send a sample code on github when I have a time.

Comment: but I am sending array of json ,, I am not sending a single json. it still dosent work ,,,,Structure of my data is like [{} , {}] - two jsons are being sent

Comment: actuall error ---- Error :Uncaught (in promise) : unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Humm, your code seems to no want to work :D . I'm implementing your issue right now. I'll push it on github and let you know when It's finish.

Comment: thanks ,,,kudos to you ,,, We will make it work as a team

Comment: Here it's : https://github.com/freemanpolys/jhipster-labs. It's an old  microservice project. I've added bath delete on Person. You have to run a Registry, the Gateway and Person services. If you inspect the two commit I've pushed, you will see what I've done : https://github.com/freemanpolys/jhipster-labs/commit/fbc1141a66dca32fbbf5c246b7695fcb50546658 and https://github.com/freemanpolys/jhipster-labs/commit/80dba7bf0a8d220d821760e497f09c61695c85bd

Comment: As I don't have your code , I've just implement the same feature you need : delete a list of entities. You just have to change Person entity by your Profile entity and you are done.

Comment: whats  JhiEventManager ??

Comment: It's an event manager service generate by jHipster for broadcasting or listening for an event. It's useful for notifying component when an entity is CRUD so that it can reload entities.

Comment: Not happening with even this dude ,,,, I appreciate your effort but ,, the only difference it made ,, to my scenario is,,, now I dont get any error either on console or on backend. Its just that the call dosent come to backend